# Rspec test failing: creating new record rather than using existing one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

I have the following code:

```
describe "when visiting roll call with no notes" do
  before do
    login_as_sensei
    @dojo = FactoryGirl.create(:dojo, name: "Melbourne")
    @time = FactoryGirl.create(:times, dojo: @dojo)
    @roll = FactoryGirl.create(:roll_call)
    visit time_roll_calls_path("melbourne", "14-2-2013", "1000")
  end

  specify { @roll.notes.should be_blank }
  it { should_not have_content("This is a note!") }

  describe "and filling in note information correctly" do
    before do
      fill_in "roll_call[notes]", with: "This is a note!"
      click_button "Add Notes"
    end

    it { should have_content("This is a note!") } # 'it' refers to the page
    specify { RollCall.last.notes.should_not be_blank }
    specify { @roll.notes.should_not be_blank }
    specify { @roll.reload.notes.should_not be_blank }
  end
end
```

As far as I know, all 4 tests at the end should pass, however only the first 2 do:

```
it { should have_content("This is a note!") }
specify { RollCall.last.notes.should_not be_blank }
```

And the last 2 return the following errors:

```
1) RollCalls when visiting roll call with no notes and filling in note information correctly 
 Failure/Error: specify { @roll.notes.should_not be_blank }
   expected blank? to return false, got true
 # ./spec/features/roll_calls_spec.rb:241:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) RollCalls when visiting roll call with no notes and filling in note information correctly 
 Failure/Error: specify { @roll.reload.notes.should_not be_blank }
   expected blank? to return false, got true
 # ./spec/features/roll_calls_spec.rb:242:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is this how rspec should work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `@roll.notes.reload` instead? (i.e. reloading the notes collection, not the RollCall object?)

Comment: @DylanMarkow just tried your suggestion, getting `undefined method 'reload' for nil:NilClass`, so basically the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing acceptance specs and request specs here. `@roll` will not be modified when you perform capybara requests (via fill_in, etc).

Acceptance specs test the contents of the response. Request specs test operations on records for a given request. You might consider splitting up your tests like so:

```
# Acceptance test
describe "when visiting roll call with no notes" do
  before do
    login_as_sensei
    @dojo = FactoryGirl.create(:dojo, name: "Melbourne")
    @time = FactoryGirl.create(:times, dojo: @dojo)
    @roll = FactoryGirl.create(:roll_call)
    visit time_roll_calls_path("melbourne", "14-2-2013", "1000")
  end

  it { should_not have_content("This is a note!") }

  describe "and filling in note information correctly" do
    before do
      fill_in "roll_call[notes]", with: "This is a note!"
      click_button "Add Notes"
    end

    it { should have_content("This is a note!") } # 'it' refers to the page
  end
end

# Request specs
describe RollCallsController do
  describe "#action" do
    before do
      login_as_sensei
      @roll = FactoryGirl.create(:roll_call)

    end

    it "should initially be blank" do
      get "/some/path", :id => @roll.id
    end

    it "should add a note" do
      post "/roll_calls/#{@roll.id}/notes/add", roll_call: {notes: "New note"}
      @roll.reload.notes.should_not be_blank
      @roll.reload.notes[0].note.should == "New note"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Chris. Does it make sense to only stick to the acceptance test in this case, or is it common practice to write both tests?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to test, really. I tend to use request tests to test the effects of a single controller action, and acceptance tests to test a series of actions.